# add filupload to method in asp web api

Tags: c#, json, api, asp.net-core, postman

My API has this method:

```
if (item.fileuploadresults != null)
   {
     foreach (FileUploadResult f in item.fileuploadresults)
     {
      var parameters = new DynamicParameters();
      parameters.Add("filename", f.filename); 
        
      var filemessage = await _sqlconnection.QueryAsync<int>($@"INSERT INTO [dbo].[OptionalFile] 
      ([FileName]) VALUES (@filename); SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY();", parameters);
        
       int FileMessageID = filemessage.First(); 
        
       //update crosstable
       await _sqlconnection.QueryAsync<int>($@"INSERT INTO[dbo].[ClaimCrossOptionalFile]
                                                         (ClaimID,FileID)
                                                          VALUES
                                                         ({claimID},{FileMessageID});");
}
```

Where the database gets updated with values based on this JSON:

```
"fileuploadresults" : [
    {"filename" : "a"},
    {"filename" : "b"},
    {"filename" : "c"},
    {"filename" : "d"}]},
```

Now, I want to actually be able to upload files into the database. I have this method i tested to upload files in postman:

```
var files = new List<IFormFile>();
                    var result = new List<FileUploadResult>();

                    foreach (var file in files)
                    {
                        var path = Path.Combine(this.iwebHostEnvironment.WebRootPath, "images", file.FileName); 
                        var stream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Create);
                        await file.CopyToAsync(stream);
                        result.Add(new FileUploadResult() { Name = file.FileName, Length = file.Length });
                    }
```

Whats the best way to sort of combine these 2 methods, so that I can upload files in postman, where it is stored in the database?

For example, instead of saving the files to the webrootpath (as it currently does in the second method), I would like to save the files directly to the database table.

Comment: Do you mean you want to upload a file and with some parameter to the asp.net core backend and then store these data into database?

Comment: yeah something like that

Comment: Normally, the file upload should be a formdata, we couldn't directly send the file trough the json format body. Could you send the fileuploadresults" though form data not json format.

Comment: the problem is that it does not seem to work to send both json and form data at the same time

Comment: Yes, we couldn't do that. If you want to combine these two requests, you should use formdata to send the fileuploadresults and the file inside the request body.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question correctly, you need to have a table with a column that can store binary data. There are different binary data types, and you should select one that fits your needs (mainly filesize). After that you can insert the binary file into the table, just like you're doing with filename etc.

Comment: do you have an example of this?